# Prevent caching of an iframe in a Flask based web-application

Tags: html, flask, iframe, browser-cache

I am really stuck with a caching problem I encounter on a programming project I am on.
Basically I am generating a Leaflet-Map with folium and store the static output on my local disk.

I then want to display this HTML inside another HTML-Page as an iframe.
The user then should be able to generate a new map with a simple form and a POST-Request to flask which then reload the page that contains the HTML with the iframe.

The problem is everything is working the page is updated on disk but it is not when the page reloads in browser. This problem is also browser independent (chrome, firefox, ege).

I have already tried multiple things:

1. Adding app.after_request:

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'
    return response
```

2. Add a random query parameter to the url of the iframe

```
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var url = "map.html?" + (new Date()).getTime();
                window.document.write("<iframe class=\"embed-responsive-item\" id=\"map\" src=" + url + "\></iframe>")</script> 
        </div>
```

3. Add Meta-tags to the HTML-Output of folium with BS:
   [Iframe-Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlbqt.png)

And still this does not have any effect on the iframe caching.
Maybe there is a better aproach to doing this or somebody already encountered a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

So for anybody facing a similar issue, try using Debug FLASK_ENV=development and set it via shell or command-line.

`set FLASK_ENV=development`

Still this can't be the ultimate solution for this problem but maybe somebody can tell what changes in Flask configuration if "development" is set.
The caching for sure happens on server side. All the response headers, meta-tags and dynamic url are working correctly.
Seems to me that flask in it's development-mode is reloading local files whenever they change on disk.